# Send variable data from Post to Get express

Tags: express

Lets say that result is an object of different documents from the database. How would I then transfer that data from the POST request into the Get request?

```
var opions = { ghost, banana, pepper, pepperoni }

result = await Load.find(options);

res.redirect('/displayFoodsSearch');
```

Answer (score 0):

nvm resolved with

```
res.render("/displayFoodSearch", {foods: result});
```